# How to use OFFSET in ARRAYFUNCTION?

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following function, which calculates the average of the previous 7 rows of the column on the left.

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(C8;-6;-1;7))
```

The problem: whenever I update the data column I have to update the average column in order to copy the formula.

I would like to fix this by using ARRAYFORMULA, but I do not know how to specify the current cell for OFFSET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [map()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) instead of an array formula. To calculate a rolling 7-day average of the values in column `B2:B`, put this formula in row `8` of a free column:

```
=map(B8:B, lambda(c, iferror(average(offset(c, -6, 0, 7)))))
```

The `map()` function gets references instead of values which lets `offset()` work properly in the enclosed [lambda](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function.

Comment: I ended using if-isnumber instead of iferror: `=map(B8:B; lambda(c; if(isnumber(c); average(offset(c;-6;0;7)); )))`